# Nginx (SSL) -> Varnish -> Apache upstream load balancing/ failsafe

Tags: apache, nginx, varnish

I want to setup the following infratructure: Nginx as ssl terminator/ load balancer in front of a Varnish cache which itself uses Apache backends.

Now I want to load balance the traffic in the following way. Primary backend should be the Varnish backend. Backup backend should be the Apache backend directly. And another backup backend, that simply shows a maintenance page, if the Varnish backend and the Apache backend is down.

I have tested the proxy_pass upstream the following ways:

```
upstream backends {
  server VARNISH-HOST;
  server APACHE-HOST backup;
  server MAINTENANCE-HOST backup;
}
```

With this setup, and Varnish offline, the system cycles throuhg both backends with round-robin - not first backup and, if offline too, second backup.

Another configuration:

```
upstream backends {
  server VARNISH-HOST weight=10;
  server APACHE-HOST;
  server MAINTENANCE-HOST backup;
}
```

But I am not sure if this is the right way?! What is the best/ right way to setup the upstream backends in the way I want them to respond? Any advice?

Regards.